# How to not Join on an Inline Table or Return a NULL value if it its result set is empty

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that returns several values, all grouped around their 'transaction type' (this can be card / cash / cheque). Some values are built from inline tables.

All of the inline tables return a common column that I can use to join them to one of my original tables.

However, there is a possiblity revealed during testing that some of the inline tables may return nothing, this breaks my query.

For example, one inline table returns total sales this year by transaction_type, another inline table returns total sales from last year by transaction_type.

Both of these inline tables are grouped by transaction_type and joined to the rest of the query by the transaction_type.

This has all been working fine in development, but during testing i've found that if we have a new department that has no sales for last year (each department uses a separate database), my inline table for last years sales returns nothing.

But since I have joins to these inline tables in the code i'm joining on nothing and my query returns nothing.

I tried to use the LEFT JOIN on my inline tables, this LEFT JOIN query also works fine when there is DATA.

However, when there is no data from some of the inline tables (such as no data for last year) the left join query runs forever (well i cancelled it at 15 minutes) but The original query returns all the columns straight away but with no data.

So I can see the problem, that i'm trying to join on things that might not be there! Does anybody know how I can get around this one? A thought I had on the way home from work was to return a null value and use COALESCE to replace it with a 0, but that doesn't help me with the joins so I'm back to #1.

I hope I provided enough information.

--Original Query--

```
declare @ToDate datetime,
        @FromDate datetime,
        @StartYear datetime,
        @Active datetime



set @ToDate = '30-nov-2010'
set @FromDate = '1-Jan-2010'
set @StartYear = '1-jan-2010'
set @active = '1-jan-2010'

select      SUM(th.total_net_retail_central) as 'Net Purchases  TY', 
            IL2.total_sum as 'Net Purchases LY',
            IL3.total_sum as 'Net Purchases YTD',
            IL6.total_sum as 'Net Purchases YTD (LY)',
            tt.Transaction_type_description as 'Channel',
            COUNT(DISTINCT th.customer_id) as 'Number of Customers TY',
            IL7.total_sum as 'Number of Customers LY',
            IL1.Active as 'Number of Active Customers TY',
            COUNT(th.transaction_id) as 'Number of Transactions TY',
            IL8.total_sum as 'Number of Transactions LY',
            IL4.total_sum as 'Total Number of Units TY',
            IL5.total_sum as 'Total Number of Units LY'

FROM        

(SELECT transaction_type, COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id) as 'Active' from transaction_header  
where transaction_date BETWEEN @Active and @ToDate group by transaction_type)IL1, 
(SELECT SUM(th.total_net_retail_central) as 'total_sum', th.transaction_type from transaction_header th 
where th.transaction_date BETWEEN DATEADD(yy, -1, @FromDate) AND  DATEADD(yy, -1, @ToDate) GROUP BY th.transaction_type)IL2,
(SELECT SUM(th.total_net_retail_central) as 'total_sum', th.transaction_type FROM transaction_header th
where th.transaction_date BETWEEN @StartYear AND GETDATE() GROUP BY th.transaction_type)IL3,
(SELECT SUM(td.quantity) as 'total_sum', th.transaction_type from transaction_detail td, transaction_header th
where th.transaction_date BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate AND th.transaction_id = td.transaction_id GROUP BY th.transaction_type)IL4,
(SELECT SUM(td.quantity) as 'total_sum', th.transaction_type from transaction_detail td, transaction_header th
where th.transaction_date BETWEEN DATEADD(yy, -1, @FromDate) AND DATEADD(yy, -1, @ToDate) AND th.transaction_id = td.transaction_id GROUP BY th.transaction_type)IL5,
(SELECT SUM(th.total_net_retail_central) as 'total_sum', th.transaction_type from transaction_header th 
where th.transaction_date BETWEEN DATEADD(yy, -1, @StartYear) AND  DATEADD(yy, -1, GETDATE()) GROUP BY th.transaction_type)IL6,
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT th.customer_id) as 'total_sum', th.transaction_type from transaction_header th
where th.transaction_date between DATEADD(yy, -1, @FromDate) AND DATEADD(yy, -1, @ToDate) GROUP BY th.transaction_type)IL7,
(SELECT COUNT(th.customer_id) as 'total_sum', th.transaction_type from transaction_header th
where th.transaction_date between DATEADD(yy, -1, @FromDate) AND DATEADD(yy, -1, @ToDate) GROUP BY th.transaction_type)IL8,
transaction_header th

INNER JOIN 
            transaction_type tt ON th.transaction_type = tt.transaction_type
WHERE 
            th.transaction_date Between @FromDate AND @ToDate
AND         IL1.transaction_type = th.transaction_type
AND         IL2.transaction_type = th.transaction_type
AND         IL3.transaction_type = th.transaction_type
AND         IL4.transaction_type = th.transaction_type
AND         IL5.transaction_type = th.transaction_type
AND         IL6.transaction_type = th.transaction_type
AND         IL7.transaction_type = th.transaction_type
AND         IL8.transaction_type = th.transaction_type
GROUP BY 
            tt.transaction_type_description, IL1.Active, IL2.total_sum, IL3.total_sum, IL4.total_sum, IL5.total_sum, IL6.total_sum, IL7.total_sum, IL8.total_sum
```

--Query Using Left Joins--

```
declare @ToDate datetime,
    @FromDate datetime,
    @StartYear datetime,
    @Active datetime



set @ToDate = '30-nov-2010'
set @FromDate = '1-Jan-2010'
set @StartYear = '1-jan-2010'
set @active = '1-jan-2010'


select SUM(th.total_net_retail_central) as 'Net Purchases  TY', 
        IL2.total_sum as 'Net Purchases LY',
        IL3.total_sum as 'Net Purchases YTD',
        IL6.total_sum as 'Net Purchases YTD (LY)',
        tt.Transaction_type_description as 'Channel',
        COUNT(DISTINCT th.customer_id) as 'Number of Customers TY',
        IL7.total_sum AS 'Number of Active Customers TY',
        IL1.Active AS 'Number of Active Customers TY',
        COUNT(th.transaction_id) as 'Number of Transactions TY',
        IL8.total_sum as 'Number of Transactions LY',
        IL4.total_sum as 'Total Number of Units TY',
        IL5.total_sum as 'Total Number of Units LY'

FROM transaction_header th

INNER JOIN  transaction_type tt ON th.transaction_type = tt.transaction_type

LEFT JOIN (SELECT transaction_type, COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id) as 'Active' from     transaction_header  
where transaction_date BETWEEN @Active and @ToDate group by transaction_type)IL1  ON  th.transaction_type = IL1.transaction_type

LEFT JOIN (SELECT SUM(th.total_net_retail_central) as 'total_sum', th.transaction_type from transaction_header th 
where th.transaction_date BETWEEN DATEADD(yy, -1, @FromDate) AND  DATEADD(yy, -1, @ToDate) GROUP BY th.transaction_type)IL2 on th.transaction_type = IL2.transaction_type

LEFT JOIN (SELECT SUM(th.total_net_retail_central) as 'total_sum', th.transaction_type FROM transaction_header th
where th.transaction_date BETWEEN @StartYear AND GETDATE() GROUP BY th.transaction_type)IL3 on  th.transaction_type =  IL3.transaction_type

LEFT JOIN (SELECT SUM(td.quantity) as 'total_sum', th.transaction_type from transaction_detail td, transaction_header th
where th.transaction_date BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate AND th.transaction_id = td.transaction_id GROUP BY th.transaction_type)IL4 on th.transaction_type = IL4.transaction_type

LEFT JOIN (SELECT SUM(td.quantity) as 'total_sum', th.transaction_type from transaction_detail td, transaction_header th
where th.transaction_date BETWEEN DATEADD(yy, -1, @FromDate) AND DATEADD(yy, -1, @ToDate) AND th.transaction_id = td.transaction_id GROUP BY th.transaction_type)IL5 on th.transaction_type = IL5.transaction_type 

LEFT JOIN (SELECT SUM(th.total_net_retail_central) as 'total_sum', th.transaction_type from transaction_header th 
where th.transaction_date BETWEEN DATEADD(yy, -1, @StartYear) AND  DATEADD(yy, -1, GETDATE()) GROUP BY th.transaction_type)IL6 on  th.transaction_type = IL6.transaction_type

LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT th.customer_id) as 'total_sum', th.transaction_type from transaction_header th
where th.transaction_date between DATEADD(yy, -1, @FromDate) AND DATEADD(yy, -1, @ToDate) GROUP BY th.transaction_type)IL7 on th.transaction_type =  IL7.transaction_type

LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(th.customer_id) as 'total_sum', th.transaction_type from transaction_header th
where th.transaction_date between DATEADD(yy, -1, @FromDate) AND DATEADD(yy, -1, @ToDate) GROUP BY th.transaction_type)IL8 on th.transaction_type = IL8.transaction_type

WHERE 
        th.transaction_date Between @FromDate AND @ToDate
GROUP BY 
        tt.transaction_type_description, IL1.Active, IL2.total_sum, IL3.total_sum, IL4.total_sum, IL5.total_sum, IL6.total_sum, IL7.total_sum, IL8.total_sum
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.  It's a modified version of your original query, using SQL Server explicit `JOIN` syntax:

Your performance issues on your original left join version may have been due to query caching - I suspect both versions are very slow, but you have been running the first version so the results were cached.  You ran the second one and there were no cached results to pull from.

With an `INNER JOIN` you will always have issues if you could have `NULL`s so you need to use `LEFT JOIN`.  If it still runs forever, you need to check  the execution plan and see what is happening.

```
declare @ToDate datetime,
        @FromDate datetime,
        @StartYear datetime,
        @Active datetime



set @ToDate = '30-nov-2010'
set @FromDate = '1-Jan-2010'
set @StartYear = '1-jan-2010'
set @active = '1-jan-2010'

select      SUM(th.total_net_retail_central) as 'Net Purchases  TY', 
            IL2.total_sum as 'Net Purchases LY',
            IL3.total_sum as 'Net Purchases YTD',
            IL6.total_sum as 'Net Purchases YTD (LY)',
            tt.Transaction_type_description as 'Channel',
            COUNT(DISTINCT th.customer_id) as 'Number of Customers TY',
            IL7.total_sum as 'Number of Customers LY',
            IL1.Active as 'Number of Active Customers TY',
            COUNT(th.transaction_id) as 'Number of Transactions TY',
            IL8.total_sum as 'Number of Transactions LY',
            IL4.total_sum as 'Total Number of Units TY',
            IL5.total_sum as 'Total Number of Units LY'

FROM        

transaction_header th

LEFT JOIN ( SELECT transaction_type, COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id) as 'Active' 
            from transaction_header  
            where transaction_date BETWEEN @Active and @ToDate 
            group by transaction_type) IL1 ON IL1.transaction_type = th.transaction_type
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT SUM(th.total_net_retail_central) as 'total_sum', th.transaction_type 
            from transaction_header th 
            where th.transaction_date BETWEEN DATEADD(yy, -1, @FromDate) AND  DATEADD(yy, -1, @ToDate) 
            GROUP BY th.transaction_type) IL2 ON IL2.transaction_type = th.transaction_type
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT SUM(th.total_net_retail_central) as 'total_sum', th.transaction_type 
            FROM transaction_header th 
            where th.transaction_date BETWEEN @StartYear AND GETDATE() 
            GROUP BY th.transaction_type) IL3 ON IL3.transaction_type = th.transaction_type
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT SUM(td.quantity) as 'total_sum', th.transaction_type 
            from transaction_detail td, transaction_header th 
            where th.transaction_date BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate AND th.transaction_id = td.transaction_id 
            GROUP BY th.transaction_type) IL4 ON IL4.transaction_type = th.transaction_type
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT SUM(td.quantity) as 'total_sum', th.transaction_type 
            from transaction_detail td, transaction_header th 
            where th.transaction_date BETWEEN DATEADD(yy, -1, @FromDate) AND DATEADD(yy, -1, @ToDate) AND th.transaction_id = td.transaction_id 
            GROUP BY th.transaction_type) IL5 ON IL5.transaction_type = th.transaction_type
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT SUM(th.total_net_retail_central) as 'total_sum', th.transaction_type 
            from transaction_header th 
            where th.transaction_date BETWEEN DATEADD(yy, -1, @StartYear) AND  DATEADD(yy, -1, GETDATE()) 
            GROUP BY th.transaction_type) IL6 ON IL6.transaction_type = th.transaction_type
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT th.customer_id) as 'total_sum', th.transaction_type 
            from transaction_header th 
            where th.transaction_date between DATEADD(yy, -1, @FromDate) AND DATEADD(yy, -1, @ToDate) 
            GROUP BY th.transaction_type) IL7 ON IL7.transaction_type = th.transaction_type
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(th.customer_id) as 'total_sum', th.transaction_type 
            from transaction_header th 
            where th.transaction_date between DATEADD(yy, -1, @FromDate) AND DATEADD(yy, -1, @ToDate) 
            GROUP BY th.transaction_type) IL8 ON IL8.transaction_type = th.transaction_type
INNER JOIN  transaction_type tt ON th.transaction_type = tt.transaction_type
WHERE 
            th.transaction_date Between @FromDate AND @ToDate
GROUP BY 
            tt.transaction_type_description, IL1.Active, IL2.total_sum, IL3.total_sum, IL4.total_sum, IL5.total_sum, IL6.total_sum, IL7.total_sum, IL8.total_sum
```

Comment: I unsderstand about the LEFT JOIN where I could have NULL's. But the problem is the inline table (such as IL3) doesn't return anything so I have a LEFT JOIN on from a table of nothing to anything in the right table. If I change them to RIGHT JOIN the query runs instantly but I get no results. Does this make sense.. If I use your modified query it runs 'forever' too. Thanks for the suggestion tho.

Comment: @Wes Price- It actually doesn't make sense to me how you are explaining it.  If you `LEFT JOIN` to a table with no results then you just get `NULL` for those fields.  In my query above `transaction_header` is your `LEFT` table and all the others are on the `RIGHT`.  If they are empty you should still get your `th` fields.

Comment: Yes this is what I thought.. it has been a busy week and my brain was a little burned out yesterday.. i'll re-go over my query and see what is what and let you know.